# Lotus Notes View unable to show all the values in separate view

Tags: view, lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I have created a field which is able to support for "multiple value" . In the Lotus Notes view, I have enabled an option "Show multiple values as separate entries" in order to show separate entry of the each value. Noticed that the Lotus Notes view is unable to show all the values in separate entries. Do you have any ideal?[image: Lotus Notes View with Separate Line![][1]]

Comment: Use document properties to check if the fields on all docs are really multi values

Comment: Yes. In this multiple values field, it has showing a text list example :"0"
"1574.16"
"462"
"462.36"
"462"
"462"
"462"
"50"
"26"
"135"
"26"
"27"
"20"
"40.23"
"26"
"-4252.75"

Comment: Is the column marked as a categorized column?

Comment: Yes :) It is really weird..if i create a text list with "1" "2" "3" "4"...."13" "14" "15". The Notes view is able to show all the numbers with separate line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option "Show multiple values as separate entries" shows only **unique** values in column.

Some of your values are several times in your list like "26" and "462". They show up in column only one time. Think of this option like a categorized column. Multiple identical values are connected to one.

If you really need to show all values then here is a workaround:

Create a second *unsorted* column right after your column with the formula

```
@Transform(list; ""; @Random)
```

This will create a unique random value for every entry in your list.

[image]

Hide the second column. Your original column will show *all* values now.

Comment: Works, but "... using the @Random function in a view is kind of weird" :-) http://goo.gl/VhMZSN

Comment: @Frantisek: it might be weird but a very efficient and performant way to get entries which are different from each other. :-)